# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' (When running eas build -p android --profile production)

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-build

I'm getting the following error when building the react-native apk app for android via expo build command for production.

Below is the package.json, eas.json and error

1. package.json ((https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pgm5.png)
2. eas.json (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY3YS.png)

ERROR ON EXPO BUILD:

> [stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> [stderr] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
> [stderr]    > Android resource compilation failed
> [stderr]      ERROR:/home/expo/workingdir/build/mobile-app-paywise/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/assets_images_registration.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
> [stderr]
> [stderr] * Try:
> [stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> [stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> [stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
> [stderr] ==============================================================================
> [stderr] 2: Task failed with an exception.
> [stderr] -----------
> [stderr] * What went wrong:
> [stderr] java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
> [stderr] * Try:
> [stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> [stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> [stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
> [stderr] ==============================================================================
> [stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> [stderr] BUILD FAILED in 5m 13s
> Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

Tried npx expo prebuild, and deleted the drawable* files, but still facing same issues.
Appreciate if anyone could help :(

Comment: Got a solution from Expo forum, in case if anyone face same issue. 
As far as I know this means that you have a file called assets/images/registration.png that is in fact not a PNG.

If you’re on macOS or Linux you can try running file assets/images/registration.png to see what type it is. If it’s actually a JPEG then you can rename it and fix the name in your code too.